# echo response PHP vs println Scala

Tags: php, scala, migration, echo, println

I have below PHP function code which echoes the server's response.

**PHP Code**

```
function printMessage($errMsg){
    $color='#ffffff';
    echo "<table style=>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor='".$color."'> ".randomFun($errMsg, 0)."</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

I have to migrate the same in Scala(new with Scala).

**Scala Code**

```
def printMessage(errMsg: String): Unit = {
val color = "#ffffff"
val formattedErrMsg = randomFun(errMsg, 0)

println(
  s"""<table style="">
     |  <tr bgcolor='$color'>
     |    $formattedErrMsg
     |  </tr>
     |</table>
""".stripMargin
)
}
```

Well, I am unsure if this will behave the same way as the echo in PHP. Looking for a way in Scala to echo the response on server as in PHP.

Comment: What is the current result? Is there is an error, no output or something else? I suggest to remove the PHP code and simplify the Scala code: the root question is “how to display HTML with Scala”, isn't it?.

Comment: How is the function printMessage called? You also have a web server running?

Comment: The functions works on Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZEDBL1ZRR662VCuNOaA6tg

Comment: @A.L Should we recommend the Play Framework? A similar functionality to PHP is not so easy to achieve with Scala. Or how do you see it?

Comment: @Twistleton I don't know Scala, I can't answer to this question sorry.

Comment: What is the question? You are unsure how it will behave? Run the code and see perhaps?

Comment: In Scala, the println command only prints the text on the console, unlike in PHP. In PHP, the script runs within a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `println` function will not work the same way as `echo` in php.
If you want to write a service in Scala, then you need to use the appropriate frameworks.

For example:

Play Framework - https://www.playframework.com/

Akka-http - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html

http4s - https://http4s.org/v0.20/service/

`println()` - this is a simple function to output a message to the console.

Comment: Would you prefer Akka-http or https4s. And why exactly this tool/framework?

Comment: Probably depends on the project. I like Akka-http, but if the cats-effect or ZIO libraries are used. I would take http4s as a basis.